# Leading bad characters

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I am receiving 3 bad characters at the beginning of my first word out of a file, using ifstream.
I have tried trimming the string, but to no avail.

```
string trim(string in){
    string out;
    int strBegin = in.find_first_not_of(" \t");
    if( strBegin == string::npos)
        return "";//nothing

    int strEnd = in.find_last_not_of(" \t");
    int strRange = strEnd - strBegin + 1;

    out = in.substr(strBegin, strRange);
    transform(out.begin(), out.end(), out.begin(), ::tolower);

    return out;
}
```

And here is the output i am getting when reading "Hello," the first word in my file.

```
� i: 0
�� i: 1
�he i: 2
hell i: 3
ello i: 4
llo i: 5
lo i: 6
o i: 7
```

And this is printed from:

```
for(int i=0; i<temp.length(); i++){
    cout<<temp.substr(i,i+1)<<" i: "<<i<<endl;
}
```

cat -vg on txt file

```
M-oM-;M-?Hello, world test
```

file actually contains "Hello, World test" as first line

Comment: `int strRange = strEnd - strRange + 1;` undefined behaviour (`strRange` is uninitialized). You probably meant `int strRange = strEnd - strBegin + 1;`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but still results in the same output.

Comment: Inspect the file with a hex viewer. I bet there are, in fact, "unusual" characters in the file before the actual data. Perhaps a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Barring that, your code [appears to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61601355a566c0e7)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That looks like what you get when you print certain UTF8 (or otherwise wide) chars to a non-UTF8 aware terminal, so I am guessing you may have an unexpected character encoding problem.

Comment: If you're using Unix/Linux - `cat -vt` is often a convenient way to check for control characters in files.

Comment: cat -vt test.txt outputs: M-oM-;M-?Hello, world test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a UTF-8 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your document consisting of the 3-byte sequence `EF BB BF` in hex (which is equivalent to `M-oM-;M-?`, in the language of `cat -vt`).

You need to either modify your program to deal with the BOM appropriately (i.e. ignore it) or re-encode your text file to remove the BOM.  Many text editing programs will not display the BOM in your document, so you may *think* it's not there, but it's there nonetheless.